# Compare 2 lists and populate final list in order using google apps script

Tags: loops, for-loop, google-apps-script

I have 2 lists in the below format.

```
  array_so_helper:
  [[01-0158969, 315.0], [01-0161045, 699.0], [01-0161046, 41.0], [01-0161047, 45.0]]

  array_so:
  [[01-0158969, null, 315.0, null], [01-0161045, null, 699.0, null], [01-0161047, null, 45.0,null]]
```

For every first element in the array_so_helper, if there is a match in second list (array_so), then write that corresponding sub-list from array_so to a final_list. If there is an element that is found in array_so_helper but not in array_so, then write it in the below format to the final_list:

```
 [01-0161046, null, 41.0, "yes"]
```

Hence the final_list has to be

```
 [[01-0158969, null, 315.0, null], [01-0161045, null, 699.0, null],[01-0161046, null, 41.0, "yes"],, [01-0161047, null, 45.0,null]]
```

I am trying to do that using 2 for loops as below:

```
 var array_so_final = [];
 for(i=0; i<array_so_helper.length; i++){
   elem = array_so_helper[i][0]
   value = array_so_helper[i][1]
   for(j=0;j<array_so.length;j++){
     elem_helper_0 = array_so[j][0]
     elem_helper_1 = array_so[j][1]
     elem_helper_2 = array_so[j][2]
     elem_helper_3 = array_so[j][3]
     if(elem == elem_helper){
       array_so_final.push([elem_helper_0,elem_helper_1,elem_helper_2,elem_helper_3])
     }
  }
}
```

Not sure how to capture if an element is missing in array_so_helper.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of undefined variables in your current code. But you can refer to this sample code:

```
function compareList() {
  
  var array_so_helper = [['01-0158969', 315.0], ['01-0161045', 699.0], ['01-0161046', 41.0], ['01-0161047', 45.0]];
  var array_so = [['01-0158969', null, 315.0, null], ['01-0161045', null, 699.0, null], ['01-0161047', null, 45.0,null]];
  var array_so_final = [];
 
  for(i=0; i<array_so_helper.length; i++){
    var elem = array_so_helper[i][0]
    var value = array_so_helper[i][1]
    Logger.log(elem);

    //search for the element in the second list
    var search = array_so.find(so =>{
      return so[0]==elem;
    });

    Logger.log(search);
    if(search){
      //match found, add to final list
      array_so_final.push(search);
    }else{
      //match not found
      array_so_final.push([elem, null, value, "yes"]);
    }
  }
  Logger.log("**FINAL**");
  Logger.log(array_so_final);
}
```

### What it does?

1. Loop all `array_so_helper` and get its `element` and `value`.
2. Find the `element` obtained in step1 in array_so using array.find()
3. If match is found, add the matched data to `array_so_final`
4. If match was not found, create a data with the following content `[element, null, value, "yes"]` then add it to `array_so_final`

### Output:

```
5:37:58 AM  Notice  Execution started
5:37:59 AM  Info    01-0158969
5:37:59 AM  Info    [01-0158969, null, 315.0, null]
5:37:59 AM  Info    01-0161045
5:37:59 AM  Info    [01-0161045, null, 699.0, null]
5:37:59 AM  Info    01-0161046
5:37:59 AM  Info    null
5:37:59 AM  Info    01-0161047
5:37:59 AM  Info    [01-0161047, null, 45.0, null]
5:37:59 AM  Info    **FINAL**
5:37:59 AM  Info    [[01-0158969, null, 315.0, null], [01-0161045, null, 699.0, null], [01-0161046, null, 41.0, yes], [01-0161047, null, 45.0, null]]
5:37:59 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```